# Pass information from one page to another using AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have to create a custom unsubscribe page in Marketing Cloud and we would like to know if it's possible to pass information from one page to another using AMPScript.

On the first page, the customer will fill in the publication list that no longer wants to receive notifications. After he clicks on the next button, a call will be made to unsubscribe that contact from the respective list in Marketing Cloud and on the next page he must fill in the reason for having done the unsubscription. After he fill in the reason for having done the unsubscription, another API call will be made to add the value populated on the second page in a field in a Data Extension with the SubscriberKey passed in the link.

As this set of pages will be filled out after receiving an email by the tool, we want to make sure that the SubsbriberKey informed in the page link and the information that will be passed in the content of the page will be transferred from one page to the other after making the steps already informed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all the necessary parameters in the url of the page. 
If this page link is being sent in the email, you can append all the parameters using [concat](https://ampscript.guide/concat/) function and [Redirecto](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) function. In the subsequent pages, you can read these parameters using [RequestParameter](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) function, and upsert data in the DE or do further processing. In case of subscriber key or any other sensitive data, you could [encrypt](https://ampscript.guide/encryption-and-encoding-functions/) the value before passing and decrypt at the receiving page before utilizing it.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: I believe also if you utilized CloudPagesURL() function to pass info from Email to Cloudpage, that you can also use this function on the cloudpage to keep passing it across each corresponding page. I am not definitive on this, but I am fairly confident that is the case.